# Open tinymce editor upon clicking icon

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Upon loading the page, I wish the tinyMCE editor to be closed.  Upon clicking an element (and not the text, thus I don't think I should use inline mode), I wish to open it.  I've found a couple ways of doing so.  Is there a "right" way, and if so, what is it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #content {height:200px;width:400px;border: 1px solid;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                // Don't want this as I want to edit upon clicking "edit" and not inline
                tinymce.init({
                    selector: '#content',
                    width : 400,
                    height: 200,
                    inline: true,
                });

                // Don't like this as I think it is ineffient, and the screen flickers
                $('#edit').click(function(){
                    tinymce.init({
                        selector: '#content',
                        width : 400,
                        height: 200
                    });
                });

                // Is this how I should do it?
                tinymce.init({
                    selector: '#content',
                    width : 400,
                    height: 200,
                    setup : function(ed) {
                        ed.on('init', function(e) {
                            e.target.hide();
                        });
                    }
                });
                $('#edit').click(function(){
                    //BOth seem to work.  What is the right way?
                    //tinymce.editors['content'].show();
                    tinymce.get('content').show();
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">Initial content goes here</div>
        <button id="edit">Edit</button>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: TinyMCE is for input type selectors, try replace your div by textarea, and set selector : 'textarea' in your init function.

Comment: @KevinGrosgojat  DIVs also work.